# Getting ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant while running Flutter iOS build. Card Scanner working fine on Android

Tags: flutter

I am getting Error when try to run Flutter run iOS. Error is 'ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'card_scanner' not found @import card_scanner;'. Card Scanner package [link](https://pub.dev/packages/card_scanner)

I have already done these things

1. Flutter clean
2. Pod deintegrate
3. Pod init
4. Pod install
5. Comment use framework! at Podfile

Here are my dependencies:

```
dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

device_info: 0.4.0+1
material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5755
provider: 3.0.0
intl: ^0.16.1
http: ^0.12.2
shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
fluttertoast: ^7.1.1
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.0
url_launcher: ^5.7.10
sqflite: ^1.3.0
path_provider: ^1.6.24
path_provider_macos: ^0.0.1
connectivity: ^2.0.2
flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.5
flutter_google_places: ^0.2.6
async: ^2.4.2
flutter_credit_card: ^0.1.4
stripe_payment: ^1.0.9
progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
intercom_flutter: ^2.3.3
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
change_app_package_name: ^0.1.2
permission_handler: 5.1.0+2
card_scanner: ^0.2.0+3
```